# Blazor JSInterop Save File

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I want to download a file that is locally located on Blazor Server.

I implemented it by referring to the link below, but the contents of the downloaded CSV file are empty.

[Blazor JSInterop Save File](https://wellsb.com/csharp/aspnet/blazor-jsinterop-save-file)

I created a csv folder in wwwroot and placed a file called table_export.csv in it.
[image]

Similarly, I created a JavaScript component called helper.js in wwwroot.

```
function FileSaveAs(filename){
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = filename;
link.href = "data:./csv/table_export.csv;charset=utf-8,"
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click();
document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

And I created a component that uses it as follows.

```
@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime


<button type="button" @onclick="@DownloadFile">
    Csv
</button>

@code {

string fileName = "csv_test.csv";

public async void DownloadFile()
{
    await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<object>(
        "FileSaveAs",
        fileName
    );
}
```

This code will start the download, but the created file will be empty and empty.

For verification, I wrote the following in the blazor component, and the contents could be downloaded in the correct state.

```
<a href="./csv/table_export.csv" download target="_top">
    download
</a>
```

Is this because the link.href in helper.js is not referencing the file correctly?

I'm sorry for the very rudimentary question, but I would like advice.
Thank you.

Comment: Your code is `link.href = "data:./csv/table_export.csv;charset=utf-8,"`
whereas the guide says  ` link.href = "data:text/plain;charset=utf-8," + encodeURIComponent(fileContent) `

Comment: Sorry for being late.
Thanks for your comment.

I made a very rudimentary misunderstanding.

If you just wanted to refer to a file that already existed, you could just write a simple description.

link.href = "./csv/table_export.csv"